# Implementing a Filterable Table in React.js with Dynamic Columns

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, filtering, dynamic-tables

I'm working on a React.js project where I need to display a table with dynamic columns. Additionally, I want to provide filtering options to users based on columns like "Operator Name," "Machine Name," etc.

I'm struggling with integrating the filtering functionality with the table. Specifically:

How can I dynamically update the table rows based on the selected filter criteria?
How can I handle multiple filter criteria efficiently?
Additional Questions:

Can anyone recommend any libraries or packages that can help simplify the implementation of a filterable table in React.js?
Are there any reference projects or tutorials that demonstrate best practices for implementing a similar feature? [image: Reference Image: I have attached an image that visually represents the desired functionality. Please refer to the attached image for a clearer understanding of what I'm aiming to achieve.]